# How to force Bazel to use gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, build, bazel

> Ubuntu 17.10
>
> GCC Version: 5.4
>
> Bazel Version: 0.9.0
>
> TensorFlow: r1.5
>
> CUDA 8.0 / cuDNN 6 / GTX 1080 Ti

How do I make Bazel use gcc for building TensorFlow from source?

While building, its running into compiler errors like:

```
error: 'errno' was not declared in this scope
while (nanosleep(&ts, &ts) != 0 && errno == EINTR) {}
```

Setting --verbose_failures flag, it shows that its not using /usr/bin/gcc-5 or /usr/bin/gcc for compiling

```
external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -fPIE -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g0 -DGEMMLOWP_ALLOW_SLOW_SCALAR_FALLBACK '-march=native' '-std=c++11' -g0 -MD -MF
```

Searching online, I found that the path to gcc and CC, CXX variables must be set in tools/cpp/CROSSTOOL. But where exactly is tools/cpp/CROSSTOOL?? How do I force bazel to use gcc-5?

Comment: Perhaps this guide will help? https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Yet-Another-CROSSTOOL-Writing-Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I know next to nothing about cuda and tensorflow, but tensorflow doesn't use the same C++ toolchain that bazel autoconfigures when compiling with cuda, so the `CC` env variable trick won't work. The file `crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc` is just a shell wrapper that could in theory still call your gcc (or it will be cuda). I'd run bazel with `--subcommands` to see the complete invocation of the failing action, then reproduce without bazel, and then go from there.